# Fetching email automatically then reading it locally

Tags: email, mail-user-agent, fetchmail

My email is kept on a remote server and accessible from anywhere by IMAP.

What I'd like is a mail client that will periodically sync that remote mail to my laptop in the backgroun, so that when I open my mail client, today's email is instantly there and does not need to be downloaded.  The background sync process could be some separate daemon or a function of the mail client itself.

What I have now is just Thunderbird accessing the remote mail server via IMAP.  But it means that mail only syncs when I start Thunderbird, and it takes ages to do so before I can read it.  It's a slow process.

I have a feeling that fetchmail could form part of what I want, as it can download mail to a local maildir.  But then what's the easiest way to access this mail locally?  And would fetchmail be smart enough to handle two-way sync, so that when I delete, move or save a mail locally the change will make its way to my remote IMAP server?

Or is there some other Thunderbird-like mail client that can sync in the background (I work in Gnome), solving my problem?

Comment: What if you just never close Thunderbird?

Comment: @alex that is a good point, though Thunderbird eats a massive amount of memory for something you might have running all the time.  It'd be good if it had a separate lightweight fetcher daemon that could run in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Fetchmail can collect your mail automatically, but it can't update the remote IMAP server with the actions you take in your local client.

[OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org/) can do what you want, although it doesn't work directly with Thunderbird (because Thunderbird doesn't support [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir)).  But you can install a local IMAP server (e.g. [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/)), tell Thunderbird to use that, and then use OfflineIMAP to keep the local and remote IMAP servers synchronized.  Or, you could switch to another client that does support Maildir, like [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/).